# Is it possible to deploy google dataflow python job template's metadata with the template (in one command)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow jobs written in python in a `main.py` file, when I want to deploy it as a template I use the following command:

```
python main.py \
    --runner=DataflowRunner' \
    --template_location=gs://dataflow-bucket/templates/my_template \
    --project=foo \
    --staging_location=gs://dataflow-bucket/staging \
    --temp_location=gs://dataflow-bucket/temp
```

I also have a metadata file named `my_template_metadata` that I currently have to separately upload using `gsutil`

```
gsutil cp my_template_metadata gs://dataflow-bucket/templates/my_template_metadata
```

Is there a way to deploy the metadata file in the same time the template is deployed ? it would be much more convenient (or is there a rational reason why it's not possible ?)